# UILongPressGestureRecognizer: action method not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to add annotation to the map when there is a long press touch been done by the user. I have implemented the code as shown in the image but the action method for some reason(*I am not able to find! :(* ) is not been called. I have checked few places and seems like its done this way only. If someone can please tell where I am doing wrong will be really great.

Currently app is terminating and giving NSInvalidArgumentException.

Thanks for help in advance! :)

[image: Code Image]

Comment: Is it userinteraction enabled?

Comment: also target should be self while adding gesture recognizer to the map view

Comment: can we still use self if I am using the code in a different class from the one which actually has the mapview outlet?

Comment: and yes userinteraction (if you mean touch feature enabled) is working. I have tested that by a hardcoded location in the map which has an annotation with title and subtitle and I am able to see that.

Comment: Yes you can use self. because as much I can see, your gesture handling method in annotation class itself.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much for helping :) Its working now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line :

```
let recognizer =  UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: mapController, action: "action:")
```

to

```
let recognizer =  UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")
```

And it will work. As your method is in self ( Annotation class) itself.

Comment: but it seems my code isn't reading any new location in action method. tap points are different but when I am converting them to location coordinates its picking up the hardcoded location. can you guess why is it so?

Comment: please add code snippet so that we can have better idea what are you trying to achieve

Comment: yes x,y coordinates.. its the same code inside action button as in the image above and changes as suggested to avoid crash. I am trying to find new coordinates and with the pre defined one I am trying to find the distance.  On printing new coordinates it gives me the one which is hardcoded. Its like conversion isn't working.

Comment: yes because you are converting mapcontroller points to mapcontroller itself. Check what actually you want to convert